# void *ptr = (int *)&a; does it not typecast the pointer

Tags: c, void-pointers

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int a = 12; 
    void *ptr = (int *)&a; 
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

In above code, at line `void *ptr = (int *)&a;` isn't the pointer is typecast to int?

Comment: `&a` _is_ an int pointer, the cast does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Per C 2018 6.5.16.1 1, when the left operand has type `void *`, the right operand may have type `int *`:

> One of the following shall hold… the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right…

Per 6.5.16.1 2, then right operand is automatically converted to the type of the left operand:

> … the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression…

Thus, in `(int *)&a`, the value of `&a`, which has type `int *`, is converted by the cast to `int *`, which has no effect. Then, for the assignment, it is automatically converted to `void *`, and the result is stored in `ptr`.

The type of `ptr` remains `void *`, as it is declared. C will not automatically track that the value in `ptr` originated from an `int *`.

Answer (score 1):

To make things short and easy (without citing the standard, which language does not help beginners).

1. You can't dereference the `void` pointer and the compiler will emit warning and errors if you try.
2. Assignment does not change the type of the object. `void *ptr = (int *)another_pointer;` **doesn't** change the type of the **`ptr`**. It is still `void` and cannot be dereferenced.

The compiler will let you know if something is not good (in most cases) like here: https://godbolt.org/z/Xm42eb